# How can we use spring cloud config server to configure log4j properties?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying to configure the log4j configuration in the config server so that I can have different log4 settings for different environments for the spring boot application.
But I am not able to find any relevant working example where I can manage the log4j configuration from config server.
Is there any way to better manage the log4j configuration using config server?

Comment: Did you check [Log4j2 Spring Cloud Config Client](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-cloud-config/log4j-spring-cloud-config-client/index.html)?

Comment: it's not very clear on how to use config server for the log4j configuration from the above link.

Answer (score 1):

I had an option to use logback or log4j so I chose to go with the logback.
To partially answer the question, I kept the logging confoiguration in the application's properties file in the config server and removed xml configuration.
It served my purpose.